# ~/.bash_profile not executed upon login, but ~/.profile is

Tags: bash, startup, profile

I'm running Ubuntu, with Gnome3 as my desktop manager. While debugging some initialization issues (the usual confusion over bash_profile, bashrc, etc.), I found that given the following files,

```
# ~/.bash_profile
export X=x

# ~/.profile
export Y=y
```

if I reboot, log in, and start a shell, it seems like `~/.bash_profile` was never sourced:

```
$ echo ${X-var_not_set}
var_not_set
$ echo ${Y-var_not_set}
y
```

I'm using Gnome terminal, running non-login shells (the default), so it makes sense that `~/.bash_profile` would not be sourced when I start a shell in the terminal emulator, but I thought `~/.bash_profile` *would* have been sourced when I originally logged in at the graphical login screen.

I'm unclear whether that login screen is the domain of the OS (Ubuntu), the graphical shell (Gnome), or something else (display manager?), and thus, what initialization files are run.

The Bash manual says that `~/.bash_profile` will be used instead of `~/.profile` if it's present, but the above behavior seems to contradict that.

> When bash is invoked as an interactive login shell, or as  a  non-interactive  shell with  the  --login  option,  it  ...  looks  for ~/.bash_profile,  ~/.bash_login,  and  ~/.profile, in that order, and reads and executes commands from the first one that exists  and  is  readable.

My best guess is that the graphical login has nothing to do with Bash (is this related to dash shell?), and as such, it executes `~/.profile`. Is that the case, or is there more to this that I'm misunderstanding?

Comment: Yeah, the answer to that question totally covers this one. Good call.